# Fill a dataset iterating resultset

Tags: java, loops, resultset

I'm trying to fill the dataset from Jfreechart by iterating the resultset.
The query from the resultset is a two colum table.
I get "Cannot resolv method setvalue(java.lang.string,ja.lang.string,int)"

```
  DefaultPieDataset dataSet = new DefaultPieDataset();
    ResultSet rs= null;
    try {
        rs = ReportDAOimpl.getInstance().getResultsFromDB(2,"12","2016");

    } catch (DAOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.printf(rs.toString());
            DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
           dataset.setValue(rs.getString("Fullname"), "Amount",rs.getInt("sum"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: According to the documentation here: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/DefaultCategoryDataset.html the `setValue` method has two versions and neither allows a String as the first parameter.